# Creating a set filled with letters from the alphabet in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a set of the letters from the alphabet and I'm not sure why the code is not working. Python gives me an error saying that the "global name 'a' is not defined." Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

```
  s = set()
  s = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}
```

Comment: strings like single letters need to be in quotes...

Answer (score 17):

`a`, `b`, ... on their own are not strings, they are names. Python strings must be enclosed in single quotes (`'a'`), double quotes (`"a"`) or triple quotes (`"""a"""` or `'''a'''`). So, the correct version of your code would be:

```
# s = set() - this is useless, the next line is already creating a set
s = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'}
```

Having said that, a much cleaner way of doing this is to use Python's built-in [set](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-set) and [string.ascii_lowercase](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) like so:

```
import string
s = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Comment: I like this answer because it at least gives a little bit of explanation, not just "Here, do this, good-bye!".  One small additional point though is that the line `s = set()` doesn't serve any purpose whatsoever. I get it: the OP had it, so this answer has it as well. But it's slightly misleading then to say "you need to have" followed immediately by a useless statement.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the wording. Any better?

Comment: Hm. Maybe a little better. Personally, I wouldn't repeat the OP's useless line of code at all. Also, I don't think the new extra information about strings is necessary. The important thing to convey is just that names and strings are different things; you did that right up front.

Comment: Noted; Thanks. More feedback welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Nice. You found a good balance between being concise and being informative. I would accept this answer. ;)

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
import string
s = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Comment: Note that `string.lowercase` won't work in Python 3, better use `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Answer (score 5):

@lenik answer is the best, but it's good to remember, that every string is also an iterable sequence and can be passed to `set()`. So, instead of list of one-letter literals you can just:

```
letters = set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz")
```

Comment: thanks. you'd be surprised, `string.lowercase` returns exactly the string you've mentioned, but much easier to type and does not require excessive squinting in an attempt to find out if some letters are missing =)

Comment: I know, just wanted to give another approach, might be useful for OP.

Comment: btw, believe that if some any weird reason I could not use `string.ascii_lowercase` I would rather `set(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)))` than typing all those letters manually... PS. `set(map(chr, range(*map(ord, 'az'))))` works too

Comment: You should add that comment to your answer.

Comment: @m.wasowski `set(map(chr, range(*map(ord, 'az'))))` does not include `z` =)

Comment: !!!BEWARE!!!: in this answer "v" character is accidentally missed! It could cause you a little headache to debug the issue, in case you copypasted it :)